# Regex to get a combo of letters and numbers range between 6-10

Tags: php, html, regex

I am fully new in regex. Finding it very confusing. I need a combination of a password that must start with a letter and must contain a combo of letters and numbers. The total length should be between 6-10. Trying to make a password validation in both client side js and server side php.

```
^[A-Za-z]+(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,9}$
```

For some reason the total length is getting added 6+9. It is not working the way it should.

Comment: You could omit the quantifier from the first character class. To match between 6 and 10 inclusive the last quantifier should be `{5,9}` as you already match 1 at the start. `^[A-Za-z](?=[^\d]*\d)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])[A-Za-z[0-9]{5,9}$` https://regex101.com/r/dp03Gp/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The start of the pattern uses a quantifier for the character class and will first match 1+ times `[a-zA-Z]` After those matches, the lookaround assertions start so the match can be longer than 6-10 characters.

In your pattern you use the dot `.{6,9}` which will match any character except a newline and will not be restricted to characters a-zA-Z and digits.

What you could do it match one time `[A-Za-z]` at the start followed by 5-9 times `[A-Za-z0-9]`.

The assertions occur after the first char, so after matching `[A-Za-z]` there should be at least a lower and uppercase a-z and a digit present.

```
^[A-Za-z](?=[^\d]*\d)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])[A-Za-z0-9]{5,9}$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Za-z]` Match upper or lowercase a-z
- `(?=[^\d]*\d)` Assert a digit
- `(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])` Assert a-z
- `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])` Assert A-Z
- `[A-Za-z0-9]{5,9}` Match any of the listed 5 - 9 times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Q0CVk/1)

```js
let pattern = /^[A-Za-z](?=[^\d]*\d)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])[A-Za-z0-9]{5,9}$/;
[
  "aA4aaaaaaa",
  "aA4a",
  "aA4aa",
  "aA4aaa",
  "aaaaaaa",
  "AAaaaaaa",
  "Pokemon12",
  "PokeMon12"
].forEach(s => console.log(s + " --> " + pattern.test(s)));
```

As pointed out in the comments by [Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte), if you want to allow a single lower or uppercase char, you could start with the assertions and match the character class `[a-zA-Z]` after. For the php version use the `\D` modifier.

```
^(?=[^\d]*\d)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{5,9}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hF7myD/1/)

Comment: in your demo, even if I do not use a number it matches. However the number and letter combination is compulsory as well.

Comment: @AnimRahman The pattern does not match when there is no number. See https://regex101.com/r/LnJ09Z/1 There must be at least one letter and one number as you stated in you question `must contain a combo of letters and numbers`

Comment: I think the problem is I am not using anything after the regex such as /m that the site uses. Do I have to use it? my string is format = /^[A-Za-z](?=[^\d]*\d)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])[A-Za-z0-9]{5,9}$/; but this shows error even if I include an input like Pokemon12 which shouldnt. Maybe it's the /m?

Comment: @AnimRahman `Pokemon12 ` does not match because after the first `P` the positive lookahead makes sure that there has to be another uppercase characters like `PokeMon12` I have added a js demo. If you want Pokemon12 to match, you could use https://regex101.com/r/BMO3aV/1

Comment: I think `[A-Za-z]` must take place after the lookaheads because at the beginning it forces the string to have at least two lowercase or two uppercase letters (that is not in the requirements). Also, and only for the php version of this pattern, to be fully rigorous, you have to use the D modifier.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Good point, the pattern would then look like `^(?=[^\d]*\d)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{5,9}$` Using `\D` modifier for the php version https://regex101.com/r/hF7myD/1/

Answer (score 0):

*[Edit: I think I may have misunderstood what you meant by "a combo of letters and numbers." In any case, just decrement the value of your second pattern because the first one "eats up" one of the characters.]*

It might be easier if you think of if this way -- it must start with one letter, then contain 5 - 9 letters/digits. So, something like `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{5,9}$` This is a pretty terrible password requirement though. There's no reason to exclude special characters and you shouldn't max out at just ten characters. I prefer to dump such arbitrary requirements completely, and instead use entropy strength checkers like [ZXCVBN](https://github.com/bjeavons/zxcvbn-php).

Comment: I understand that, I know it's a terrible requirement I am not actually using it. I am just learning regex and trying to understand it. There are lots of combinations and ways of it and I don't get it. The expression you provided does not make it compulsory to use a number.

Comment: Ah yeah ok, I see what you mean now, I did misunderstand your description.